# error while converting IST date to EST date in perl

Tags: perl, datetime-format

I am using the following code for changing the time from IST to EST... But Perl says "invalid offset : IST" and The timezone 'EST' could not be loaded, or is an invalid name.

Can any one please help?"

```
use DateTime; 
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;  
my $val = "20090103 12:00";  
my $format = new DateTime::Format::Strptime(                 
                    pattern => '%Y%m%d %H:%M',          
                                            time_zone => 'IST',                 );  
my $date = $format->parse_datetime($val);  
print $date->strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M %Z")."\n";  
$date->set_time_zone('EST');  
print $date->strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M %Z")."\n";
```

Comment: Using indirect object notation (`new DateTime::Format::Strptime(..)`) is a bad habit. Use `DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(...)` instead.

Answer (score 5):

According to [this site](http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/), `IST` is used for several countries:

```
IST Israel Standard Time    Asia    UTC + 2 hours
IST India  Standard Time    Asia    UTC + 5:30 hours
IST Irish  Standard Time    Europe  UTC + 1 hour
```

So, instead of using `IST`, use for example `Europe/Dublin`

Answer (score 1):

Use an Olson DB time zone names like "Asia/Jerusalem" and "America/New_York" instead of "IST" aund "EST". You can look them up [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

See http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-TimeZone/lib/DateTime/TimeZone.pm and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database for details

Answer (score 0):

Instead of IST, use the Olsen name of Asia/Kolkata.